# Response.outputstream.write vs Response.BinaryWrite

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpresponse, outputstream

We use the below code to show PDF files using Response.BinaryWrite. We are exploring new options as to optimize the user performance.

```
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

        if (Page.Request!=null && Page.Request.Browser!=null && 
            (!(Page.Request.Browser.Type.Contains("IE") || Page.Request.Browser.Type.Contains("InternetExplorer"))))
        {
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", buffer.Length.ToString());
        }

        Response.AddHeader("Content-Encoding", "deflate");
        if (Request.Browser.Browser == "IE" && Request.Browser.MajorVersion < 7)
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=document.pdf");            
        Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);//Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
        Response.End();
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();
```

I read that Response.outputstream.write is another option to render the PDF. 
Using  Response.outputstream.write will have any added advantage ?

Comment: Did you try it? What was the result?

Comment: @mason their was no change in terms of the behavior. I could not tell the performance part.

Comment: If there was no performance change, then why would you change it in the name of optimizing user performance?

Comment: @mason Because he's an inexperienced dev here for guidance, encouragement, and advice.

Comment: @TheSoftwareJedi I didn't ask you. Have you heard of the [Socratic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socratic_method) of teaching? The point is to ask questions that get them to critically think about their issue, rather than just asking someone to give them the answer. Often works better than just telling someone the answer.

Comment: @mason I see what you're doing - that's a great approach in a mentoring scenario over synchronous messaging. SO needs to integrate chat better.  I like my Q&A sites to be Q&A, but somehow incorporating teaching in a unobtrusive manner would be fantastic.

Comment: Read the question complete. My question was **Using Response.outputstream.write will have any added advantage ?** Asking a question wouldn't make one inexperienced. If you know,educate.

Comment: @ramdev No, asking questions doesn't make one inexperienced. Even experienced users can ask questions - they often ask great questions. However, I can tell from your question that you are inexperienced, at least in the area of making performance optimizations. Hence why I asked the question I did. Please think about it, and try to answer it after giving it some critical thought.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not have any advantage.  The code for BinaryWrite simply calls Write on the OutputStream as you are already doing:

```
public void BinaryWrite(byte[] buffer)
{
  this.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

**Using a tool such as DotPeek you can step right into compiled code and look at what it is doing.**  That's what I did in this case.  DotPeek is free and available from JetBrains.

This can help you research these things yourself instead of having to guess, test, or ask.

Comment: what are the other alternatives ?

Comment: @ramdev Alternatives to what?

Comment: Alternative to using OutputStream.Write

Comment: @ramdev Why? Why do you need an alternative to that?

Comment: @mason BinaryWrite or OutputStream.Write does solve my problem.I would like to know If there is a better to write binary data to Respons. If there is any . Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're experiencing rendering delays, you could implement an async method and use the following code:

```
var result = Response.OutputStream.BeginWrite(buffer, 0, BufferedStream.Length, null, null);
Response.OutputStream.EndWrite(result);
```